# Table scraping Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to parse this table: http://kuap.ru/banks/8012/balances/en
However, I ran into a problem: the table includes lots of options for drop-down lists (which I don't need), and tbody seems to end unexpectedly somewhere in the beginning of the table.

So, basically, I've got three questions:

1. Could you please provide working code to parse the whole table? To parse the table and turn it into a dataframe
2. Is it possible to parse from specific line in this kind of table? Like "start with id..." How?
3. Is it possible to parse only a specific column in a table like this? (Where columns don't have specific IDs). For example, can I scrape the data only from the first two columns (names and first column with numbers?)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("http://kuap.ru/banks/8012/balances/en", skiprows=[0])[-1]

df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Didn't know there is so simple solution through pandas. Can it be that easy with BeautifulSoup?